# How do I access express req inside next.js App

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

Suppose I have a middleware that adds some data fields to express.js `req` object. I want to inject these fields into my React components through my Next.js `_app.js` implementation. How do I access `req` inside `_app.js`?

Comment: You can create a route in app.js which your React app will call. The route in app.js can supply the data to the react app as JSON. For example: `app.get('/some-route', (req, res) => { var someVar=dataFromDatabase; res.json(someVar);});` You could use req.someVar instead of var someVar but that is not necessary.

Comment: @user3425506 This is completely different from what I am asking. The question is about Next.js which is an SSR framework. We don't need Next.js to make ajax calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this `static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {` and inside the function `ctx.req`

Comment: note that adding getInitialProps to your _app file will disable Automatic Static Optimization. see: "Adding a custom getInitialProps in your App will disable Automatic Static Optimization in pages without Static Generation." via: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app#caveats